# Frequency alias in pandas date_range for non business days

Tags: python, pandas

[`pandas.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) mentions a [frequency aliases doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-offset-aliases) that includes several aliases like `B` for business day frequency, but it's not clear if there is one for including only non business days (i.e. SAT and SUN only).

Is there an alias one can use to specify only SAT and SUN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alias you want is `'C'` with `pd.bdate_range` for custom business date range (bit of a misnomer for this situation).  You also need to define additional parameters. Specify that you just want `'Sat Sun'` as your `weekmask` (days you want to include). You can further include a Holiday Calendar if you want to exclude those.

```
import pandas as pd

pd.bdate_range(start='2010-01-01', end='2010-02-01', freq='C', weekmask='Sat Sun',
               holidays=None)

#DatetimeIndex(['2010-01-02', '2010-01-03', '2010-01-09', '2010-01-10',
#               '2010-01-16', '2010-01-17', '2010-01-23', '2010-01-24',
#               '2010-01-30', '2010-01-31'],
#              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='C')
```

---

If you need to keep the `pd.date_range` then you can create your custom frequency using `pd.offsets`.

```
my_freq = pd.offsets.CustomBusinessDay(holidays=None, weekmask='Sat Sun')
pd.date_range(start='2010-01-01', end='2010-02-01', freq=my_freq)
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to do it with date_range? For context I am using a package that is invoking date_range and I can only pass the freq to it. If there is not I can modify it to use what you suggested but I was wondering if there was a way with date_range and freq only.